# How do I stop a loop using a command in discord?

Tags: python, loops, discord, discord.py, bots

```
if message.content.startswith("*run"):
    ticker = message.content[5:]
    try:
      df = exchange.fetch_ohlcv(ticker)
      await message.channel.send('Read Command: will send message if long or short opportunity arises!')
      valid = True
    except:
      await message.channel.send('Invalid ticker')
    if valid == True:
      bars = exchange.fetch_ohlcv(ticker, timeframe='5m', limit=210)
      df = pd.DataFrame(bars, columns=['time','high', 'low', 'open','close', 'volume'])
      close = df.iloc[-1]['close'] 
      while valid == True:
        if message.content == "*stop":
          valid = False
        trade = strat1(ticker)
```

The code above is for a discord bot that a friend and I are working on for a side project. My problem is in the last few lines of the code,

```
while valid == True:
    if message.content == "*stop":
      valid = False:
```

When a user types in *run (ticker) in discord, the code searches through data to see whether that ticker is valid or not and then based on the response, a loop will run. During that loop, I want the user to have the option to stop it without having to turn off the bot completely, but I can't seem to get it to register the *stop command. Every time I run it, it just moves past that command completely. So, if anyone knows how to fix this, please let me know.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is to interrupt a running execution. To do it in Python, you will need to use a multiprocessing algorithm.

You can try to use the `multiprocessing` module,

Firstly, design a master thread that listens for command in the discord server, which you already did.

Then you would wanna put the actual service, that needs to be run after the command, in a function

```
def thread_worker():
  bars = exchange.fetch_ohlcv(ticker, timeframe='5m', limit=210)
  df = pd.DataFrame(bars, columns=['time','high', 'low', 'open','close', 'volume'])
  close = df.iloc[-1]['close']
  trade = strat1(ticker)
```

Then when a command to start is received, you can initiate a new process and run the corresponding job

```
newProcess = multiprocessing.Process(target=thread_worker)
newProcess.start()
```

When your master thread receives the kill signal

```
newProcess.terminate()
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining how to get the multiprocessing module? We're coding on replit and we keep getting an error. If there isn't a solution could you recommend an alternate method?